# click to message on whatsapp api without phone number

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapi

If anyone clicks on my hyperlink then he will be redirected to my WhatsApp. I already know how it is possible by using WhatsApp API like,

`https://wa.me/<number>`

But recently I saw one of person link when I clicked on it it shows the name rather than number on the screen. His link looks like,

`https://api.whatsapp.com/message/ZAPEQ6LY2F2WP1`

I searched a lot on google but can not get how I can create this type of link.

Answer (score 0):

It is provided with Whatsapp Business tools. If you are a business owner,  you can create such a link with  Business tools bundled with wa4b.

Answer (score -3):

![see the screenshot attached here]

Screenshot is attached
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6SbN.jpg)